# Sheets formula to transpose, split and repeat multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I'm looking for a script that will transpose, split and repeat multiple columns by a value in another cell.

I have it working for one column but wondered if it possible to do it for multiple columns:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(C2 & ",",A2),",",false,true))
```

Working sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W5kFTNF6g0DI1W_lHJJU91CBwL_YnEiLLb_NYH7GkLQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your desired output has duplicate products with absolutely nothing unique about them, is that supposed to make sense or be useful somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or try this shorter one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B2:B&",", A2:A^2)), ",")), 
               TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C2:C&",", A2:A)),   ","))})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed a typo on my desired output. Please could you take another look and amend your code. Sorry.

Comment: @player0 How would I modify this formula so it only repeats a single time?

Comment: Here is the solution if you only wanted to repeat a single time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026902/how-to-transpose-split-multiple-columns-and-repeat-specific-cells-in-a-column

Answer (score 0):

The following code will output exactly as you asked.

```
=arrayformula({transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B2:B4 & ",",A2:A4^2)),",",false,true)),transpose(split(concatenate(REPT(C2:C4 & ",",A2:A4)),",",false,true))})
```