# How to transpose & split multiple columns and repeat specific cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets, split, concatenation, transpose, google-query-language

I am looking to transpose, split, and keep the correct corresponding Category/Reference Number.

- Column A: Category / Reference Number.
- Column B: Email (CSV)

```
| A |        B           |    | A |  B   |
|001|Email1,Email2,Email3|    |001|Email1|
|002|Email4,Email5,Email6|    |001|Email2|
|   |                    |    |001|Email3|
|   |                    |    |002|Email4|
|   |                    |    |002|Email5|
|   |                    |    |002|Email6|
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214738/sheets-formula-to-transpose-split-and-repeat-multiple-columns) is another post which is similar to what I am looking to accomplish. The only difference is in this post, the OP requested that the formula duplicates data X times. Here is the formula that is used:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B2:B&",", A2:A^2)), ",")), 
           TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C2:C&",", A2:A)),   ","))})
```

I have tried modifying this formula by removing the "^2", "A2:A" replacing with a COUNTIF (to determine the number of emails in each row), and keep breaking the formula.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uAIr4bY1boGl2qsl85TkqlpjcQO5LGUqZFGUC8dxuPQ/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT('Form Responses'!C2:C, ","))="",,
 'Form Responses'!B2:B&"×"&SPLIT('Form Responses'!C2:C, ","))), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null")))
```

[image]