# Split and repeat without

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DT_D897EGy2BGQC7G6XEzU98u-cm4s5pIp3p268Q9Q0/edit?usp=sharing) sheet, I've the below input data:

[image]

As seen, the `courses` are separated by `/`

I want to display the same in the format below, where each line shows one course only, with the data of the student repeated:

[image]

I know using `=split(C3," / ",true,true)` can split the courses into 2 columns at the same row, but I need them in the same column, so I tried `=TRANSPOSE(split(C3," / ",true,true))` that is working fine for the first line only, but it fail with using `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Any thought? I'm opened for any potential solution, formula or script or any other.

**UPDATE**
I tried this trick, creating a new column showing number of courses for each student as `=ArrayFormula(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(C11:C13, "[^/]", ""))+1)`

[image]

Then using `Rep` to repeat each row based on the number of courses `=arrayformula({transpose(split(concatenate(rept(B11:B13 & ",",D11:D13)),",",false,true)),transpose(split(concatenate(REPT(C11:C13 & ",",D11:D13)),",",false,true))})` then ended up with:

[image]

But here, I've the courses still joint together, how can i split them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added two sheets to your sample spreadsheet. "Sheet2" is a cleanup of your testing sheet, "Sheet1." The other sheet ("Erik Help") references Sheet2, not Sheet1, and contains the following formula in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Student ID","Student Name","Course";SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FILTER(SUBSTITUTE("/ "&Sheet2!C3:C,"/","/ "&Sheet2!A3:A&"zzz~"&Sheet2!B3:B&"~"),Sheet2!A3:A<>""),"/")),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"),"~"),"zzz","")})`

This one array formula produces all headers and results.

A virtual array is formed between the curly brackets { }. Headers are introduced first followed by a semicolon, which means "bump down one row to continue." The header titles can be changed as you like.

**How It Works:**

An addition "/ " is concatenated to the front of every non-blank entry in Sheet2!C2:C. Then `SUBSTITUTE` replaces every one of these forward slashes with Col A data, "zzz~", Col B data and "~". The tildes (~) will be used later by the outer `SPLIT`. The "zzz" is added to make sure that ID numbers are converted to text so that they hold formatting throughout the processing and don't turn into real numbers; later, the outer `SUBSTITUTE` will replace those with null (i.e., get rid of the 'zzz').

Once the initial concatenations are complete, they are `SPLIT` at the forward slash and then `FLATTEN`ed into one column. `QUERY` removes any blank rows in this virtual array so far. The remaining results are again `SPLIT` at the tilde. Finally, that outer `SUBSTITUTE` removes the temporary instances of 'zzz'.

I also added a custom CF formula for the alternating color banding on alternate rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, Hasan. Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

#### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(C3:C5, "/"))="",,
 A3:A5&"×"&B3:B5&"×"&SPLIT(C3:C5, "/"))), "×"), 
 "where Col3 is not null")))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [How to transpose & split multiple columns and repeat specific cells in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026902/how-to-transpose-split-multiple-columns-and-repeat-specific-cells-in-a-column)