# Convert multi column data in a single row that contains delimiter, to a multi row and flatten delimiter so only one item is in each cell

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, flatten

I am looking to split, and flatten, with an array formula, and keep the correct corresponding Reference Number, assigned to multiple rows of flattened data.

- Column A: Reference Number
- Column B: ID (CSV)
- Column C: TEMP ID (CSV)

**Current Format**

```
| A |        B      |       C      |
|111|001 002        |              |
|222|004 005 006 008|              |
|333|007            |T001 T006 T002|
|888|               |T005 T004 T008|
|444|               |T007          |
```

**Expected Results**

```
| A | B | C  |
|111|001|    |
|111|006|    |
|222|004|    |
|222|005|    |
|222|006|    |
|222|008|    |
|333|007|    |
|333|   |T001|
|333|   |T006|
|333|   |T002|
|888|   |T005|
|888|   |T004|
|888|   |T008|
|444|   |T007|
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026902/how-to-transpose-split-multiple-columns-and-repeat-specific-cells-in-a-column) is another post which is similar to what I am looking to accomplish.
(The only difference is in this post, the OP only had 2 columns.)

**Here is the formula that I'm using (Not working perfectly):**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT('Form Responses'!C2:D, " "))="",,
'Form Responses'!B2:B&"×"&SPLIT('Form Responses'!C2:D, " "))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null")))
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PhYmXVs6EczNmHPN4nWcILqc5GNEnw9Zg4BYQJ3hss4/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```excel
=arrayformula( 
  regexreplace( 
    text( 
      split( 
        query( 
          flatten( iferror( 'Form Responses'!B2:B & "µ" & iferror(split('Form Responses'!C2:C, " ")) & "µ" & iferror(split('Form Responses'!D2:D, " ")) ) ), 
          "where Col1 is not null and not Col1 ends with 'µµ' ", 
          0 
        ), 
        "µ", false, false 
      ), 
      "000" 
    ), 
    "000", "" 
  ) 
)
```

Note that this formula will produce a row that looks like this:

| Reference | #ID | Temp ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | 007 | T001 |

I.e., source data rows that have both an `ID` and a `Temp ID` will share a reference number. To make these IDs go to their own rows, use this:

```excel
=arrayformula( 
  regexreplace( 
    text( 
      split( 
        { 
          query( 
            flatten( iferror( 'Form Responses'!B2:B & "µ" & iferror(split('Form Responses'!C2:C, " ")) & "µ" ) ), 
            "where Col1 is not null and not Col1 ends with 'µµ' ", 
            0 
          ); 
          query( 
            flatten( iferror( 'Form Responses'!B2:B & "µµ" & iferror(split('Form Responses'!D2:D, " ")) ) ), 
            "where Col1 is not null and not Col1 ends with 'µ' ", 
            0 
          ) 
        }, 
        "µ", false, false 
      ), 
      "000" 
    ), 
    "000", "" 
  ) 
)
```

The result table will have all the `ID` rows first, followed by the `Temp ID` rows.

Comment: Thank you so much @doubleunary Your formula works way better than mine, but still has a slight issue. I should have communicated better. `ID`, and `Temp ID` are never partnered. A `Temp ID` is used when an `ID` is not present. They are all considered unique. With your formula, everything works except for ID `007` being on the same row as `T001` - I have updated the Google Sheet with your formula on the tab `Form Responses (Formatted)` which you can compare the Expected Results to see the difference. Do you have any suggestions on how to adjust the formula to accommodate this? Thanks again!

Comment: Edited the answer to include second formula to put `ID`s and `Temp ID`s in their own rows.

Comment: Thnaks! working much better. @doubleunary Do you have any suggestions on sorting the data by the reference number? I attempted to add to the query `order by Col1 asc` but the does not want to work with the formula. Currently the reference # `999` is on row 10, and the rest are on 18, and 19. Seems as if its sorting based on `ID`, then `Temp ID`.

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in `query( ... , "order by Col1", 0 )`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for all your hard work! Its perfect!